Interrupt blocking read
I have a thread doing a read syscall, and I need to interrupt it without terminating the entire process. I have tried registering a dummy handler for SIGINT using sigaction() (it returns 0, and ^C runs my handler), and then calling pthread_kill to send SIGINT specifically to the thread in question (it captures pthread_self prior to the read call), but the signal handler doesn't run, and the process appears to be violently terminated, and also something strange happens to the terminal; it stops echoing my input, and I have to exit the sudo session and restart it.
Complicating matters is that I am writing code in C#. I'm pretty sure I have the type correct; the marshaller indicates that it has the same size as struct sigaction in C code, and my custom handler is in fact run when I send ^C interactively.
Is there a different way to set signal handlers for threads/for pthread_kill? Not sure what to try next.
Code:

Definitions:

  public delegate void SignalHandler(int signal);

  [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
  public struct sigaction_t
  {
    public SignalHandler? sa_handler;
    public long sa_mask_0; // C# does not support having arrays be inlined in structures
    public long sa_mask_1;
    public long sa_mask_2;
    public long sa_mask_3;
    public long sa_mask_4;
    public long sa_mask_5;
    public long sa_mask_6;
    public long sa_mask_7;
    public long sa_mask_8;
    public long sa_mask_9;
    public long sa_mask_10;
    public long sa_mask_11;
    public long sa_mask_12;
    public long sa_mask_13;
    public long sa_mask_14;
    public long sa_mask_15;
    public int sa_flags;
    public Action? sa_restorer;
  }

  [DllImport("c")]
  public static extern int sigaction(int signum, ref sigaction_t act, IntPtr oldact);


Registering handler for SIGINT:

    NativeMethods.sigaction_t int_handler = new();

    int_handler.sa_handler = (_) => { Console.WriteLine("Handler for SIGINT"); };

    int result = NativeMethods.sigaction(NativeMethods.SIGINT, ref int_handler, IntPtr.Zero);

    if (result != 0)
      throw new Exception("sigaction failed");


Thread that needs to be interruptible:

    var monitorThread = NativeMethods.pthread_self();

    cancellationToken.Register(
      () =>
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Calling pthread_kill");
        NativeMethods.pthread_kill(monitorThread, NativeMethods.SIGINT);
        Console.WriteLine("pthread_kill finished");
      });

...

    while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
      int readSize = NativeMethods.read(_fd, buffer, BufferSize);

...

In the cancellation handler, Calling pthread_kill appears on stdout but pthread_kill finished does not. No code after the call to read appears to be executed.
I have confirmed that pthread_self returns different values in the entrypoint method and in the place doing the blocking read.

Hmm, maybe I create a pipe and then throw the pipe fd and my read fd into an fd_set and select on that, and then it'll wait until there's something to read but I can interrupt the wait by writing something to the pipe?

This alternative approach is working.
